# crm 2011 field in valuerule of displayrule of another entity

Tags: entity, hide, dynamics-crm-2011, ribbon

Can I set field of the valueRule of some DisplayRule from another entity?

say I'm in account entity and I want to show some button if the user has some custom permission which is set in systemUser entity..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you may be best off by using a role and seeing if the user has the role or not.

Comment: This is some custom permission (custom attribute) that I've added to the systemUser entity so thats why I need to access it from the account entity to see if user has permissions do use the button..

Comment: I understand.  I'm just saying there is already out of the box stuff that does this.  If you want to stick with the custom attribute route, you can use Fetch to query the systemUser entity from the Account form (or use OData).

Comment: but then I'll have to use some javascript function right? I just didnt find any solution to call the javascript function from displayrule and not from enablerule. Or am I missing something? If there is a way to set the displayRule to depend on some javascript function then it will solve all my problems :)

Comment: Yes, only enableRule allows for a custom javascript function call.  Where are you wanting to add this to the ribbon (the Form, Grid or SubGrid)?

Comment: Form..any idea how I can do it?:)

Comment: There are several options.  
(1) use JavaScript to hide the button 
(2) use the DisplayRule > valueRule with a plugin on the retrieve

I'd still convert the custom attribute to a role and then use the EnableRule and not even worry about the display rule.  However if that isn't an option, I'd use JavaScript to hide the button.